# To what level can you send a ? bitizen?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

As of the latest build of TDS, 1.2.2268 you can now send ? bitizens to any level.  In fact the game now gives you a pop-up encouraging you to try to unlock scenes, and another pop-up telling you that you will get a buying frenzy for delivering them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can send them to any level then, and they'll buy an item and take a minute off the restock timer as usual. This works to your advantage since you can either send them to a level that needs them or to a level that'll unlock a scene from the character/store combo.

Comment: Another neat trick, if you want to earn more credit, deliver them to the top level and earn double the tip of that long ride.